# <!DOCTYPE html> ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to render the cart.ejs file in a post request.

My cart.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cart-container">
        <p id="cart-title">Your<strong>Cart</strong></p>
        <div id="empty-cart">
            <h1>Your Cart is Empty..</h1>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

carts.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const Cart = require('../model/cart');


router.post('/',async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.params.name);
    const carts= new Cart({
        name:req.body.name,
        qty:parseInt(req.body.quantity)
    });

    

    try{
    const a= await carts.save();
        res.render('cart');

    console.log(carts);
    }catch(err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }   
});

module.exports = router;
```

I cannot find out what the error is.. I am getting  ^  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error while running the server. I checked all the possible answers in stack overflow but couldn't help.

Comment: **Where** are you getting the error? Is it in the browser console or the terminal where you are running Node.js? Does it tell you what file / URL the error is in? Does it give you a line number?

Comment: Using the live demo feature of the question editor is great… when it demonstrates the problem. It doesn't here so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I am getting this error in nodjs terminal.

Comment: complete error:<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Win10\shopping\app.js:54:12)

Comment: app.js 54th line :var cart = require('./views/cart.ejs');

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var cart = require('./views/cart.ejs');
> ```

`require` is used to load JavaScript modules (usually in CommonJS module format but sometimes in ES6 module format).

EJS files are **not** JavaScript modules. They need to be loaded using an EJS compiler (which, when you are are using Express, is typically done with the `render` method as described in [Using Template Engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) in the Express.js guide. i.e. what you are doing in carts.js.

I've no idea why you are trying to `require` one, you haven't provided app.js,  but don't.

Comment: I just included the path so that I can render the file by just mentioning the name of the file. ie, res.render('cart') as I did in the code..let me know if it is the reason for the error.

Comment: You specify where `render` reads files from using, for example (and copying from the link in this answer) `app.set('views', './views')`, **not** by `require()`ing the template file.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I find some small grammar error in My cart.ejs.

Before `</body>`, `</div>` tag is missing.

```
<body>
    <div id="cart-container">
        <p id="cart-title">Your<strong>Cart</strong></p>
        <div id="empty-cart">
            <h1>Your Cart is Empty..</h1>
        </div>
    </div> // this end div tag must be here.
</body>
```

Comment: There's no way that typo will trigger the error the question is asking about.

Comment: ya I closed div tag still got the same error